# Use variables in side insert or update query in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I am working on sql script in which i need to insert record in the db only if record is missing in the table , if record do exists in the table i need to update the `template` Here is my sql query

```
insert into deployment.nodes values('sind','11', now(),'temp',
   '<table id="producttable">
 <thead>
    <tr>
  <td>UPC_Code</td>
  <td>Product_Name</td>
  </tr>
  </thead>
 <tbody>
   <!-- existing data could optionally be included here -->
 </tbody>
</table>

<template id="productrow">
<tr>
 <td class="record"></td>
   <td></td>
 </tr>
 </template> ')  on conflict on constraint nodes_pkey 
DO UPDATE SET latest=now(), status='active',
agent='<table id="producttable">
<thead>
<tr>
  <td>UPC_Code</td>
  <td>Product_Name</td>
  </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
 <!-- existing data could optionally be included here -->
 </tbody>
</table>
<template id="productrow">
  <tr>
   <td class="record"></td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
 </template>'
```

This sql script is working fine for me but i want to use `HTML` stuff in a variable to minimize the length of sql script.

lets say

```
var template = '<html> ....  </html>'  and then query will be like 
insert into deployment.nodes values('sind','11', now(),'temp',template)  on conflict on constraint 
nodes_pkey   DO UPDATE SET latest=now(), status='active',agent=template
```

Comment: you can store it in a function as the return value?

Comment: @VynlJunkie any hint how do get those ?

Comment: `set agent = EXCLUDED.agent`  See here:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html

Comment: @MikeOrganek couldn't understand from the ink could you please give a small example

Answer (score 3):

Example of using the `EXCLUDED` pseudotable:

```
insert into deployment.nodes values('sind','11', now(),'temp',
   '<table id="producttable">
 <thead>
    <tr>
  <td>UPC_Code</td>
  <td>Product_Name</td>
  </tr>
  </thead>
 <tbody>
   <!-- existing data could optionally be included here -->
 </tbody>
</table>

<template id="productrow">
<tr>
 <td class="record"></td>
   <td></td>
 </tr>
 </template> ')  on conflict on constraint nodes_pkey 
DO UPDATE 
  SET latest = EXCLUDED.latest, 
      status = EXCLUDED.status,
      agent = EXCLUDED.agent
```